# How can I pagination with bootstrap-vue?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

By using "b-pagination-nav"
Given that there are a total of 33 posts and we want to show 5 posts per page, there will be a total of 7 paginations.
At this time, I want to show the paging buttons to be displayed on the screen by cutting them into 1,2,3 and cutting them into 4,5,6.
If you use the ":limit" prop, it will show 3 numbers, but it will show 3 numbers in a row.
How can i solve it?

Thank you for help us.

I used per-page, limit, number-of-pages, total-rows etc...
and I searched on many website and read the manual. but I can't resolve it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, could you clarify what you have now vs. what you need?

Answer (score 0):

```js
<template>
    <div>
      <b-pagination
        v-model="currentPage"
        :total-rows="totalRows"
        :per-page="perPage"
        :limit="limit"
        align="center"
        class="pagination"
      ></b-pagination>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        currentPage: 1,
        totalRows: 33,
        perPage: 5,
        limit: 3,
      };
    },
  };
  </script>
```